# Android - getString method error

Tags: android, string, arrays

I've got a slight problem with a getString function in my Android code.

I create a string and I want to use it to retrieve a String which is part of a JSON Array but I get the following error:

```
The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String
```

This is the specific code for this section:

```
private void read_JSON()
    {
    JSONArray jsa2 = new JSONArray();
        for (int i=0; i < jsa2.length(); i++)
        {


        try
        {
            JSONObject jso2 = new JSONObject();
            jso2 = jsa2.getJSONObject(i);
            String one = one.getString("Blur");
            //esbrinar com arreglar aixo!!


        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

    }
```

"Blur" is a String which is part of a JSONArray, defined here:

```
private void create_JSON()
    {
        JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jso.put("Nombre","Miguel");
            jso.put("Apellidos", "Garcia");
            jso.put("Año_nacimiento", 1990);
            JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray();
            jsa.put("Blur");
            jsa.put("Clur");
            jso.put("Nombres_Hijos", jsa);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Yours sincerely,

Mauro.

Comment: getString("Blur") is actualy from your JSONObject, check that

Answer (score 1):

`jso2.getString("Blur")` might be what you're trying to call. I believe you want to extract a string from the JSONObject you just got from JSONArray. What you actually wrote is to extract string from the string you just defined.

Comment: Yeah. I think I've made a mess here by trying to imitate an example I saw online. I'll redo it. Sorry for the bother.